# Rubocop: Ignore all cops that are boilerplate from a new rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rubocop

When I run `rubocop` in my app directory, I get a long list of cops that stem from the default boiler-plate rails app which I just generated.

I don't want rubocop to look at these files since I'm not the author of the files and I don't want to mess around with them.

I see that I can add files to the `Exclude:` section with `rubocop/config/default.yml` but I'm not sure what configs and files I should be adding to properly ignore the built in files while not ignoring the files I create.

Comment: Running `rubocop | grep -o '^[^ ]*.rb' | uniq` will give you a concise list of the affected files (on 'nix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `rubocop --auto-gen-config` and this will create a todo file for you which you can disable all the cops in. Then you can selectively turn the ones you want back on. Alternatively you can create a boiler plate rails app and run rubocop and those will be the files you need to add the excludes list.